# Define global variables through an application

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to define a set of global variables to be available through the entire application.

For example:
Using NodeJS, I have a a client/server application; the server side runs as a "type": "module", while the public folder is not.

Problems am trying to get solved:

1. I can call __dirname from the server.js (before I call the app), once inside the app, I can not call/request the value of __dirname
2. Am also looking to be able to define global variables through the rest of application, not only __dirname, but in general. What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: In *both* server and public? / Check `dotenv` package, it could be fine for simple globals

Comment: The client and the server are two separate applications. They do not share variables. Of course you can define global constants with the same name and value in each, but they're still separate.

Comment: Do you want it to be available in the client and the server at the same time ?

Comment: Originally, I created only one .env on the root of my project, not in /server/ nor in /public/. Would that work?. 
After that, I created a /public/.env ; then added require('dotenv').config( ); inside /public/index.js; the page wouldn't start; I had to remove that line. 
How can I call .env from within the public folder?

Comment: @walox yes or I can have independent.... just not been able to import it from public/index.js